# How to get return type from type of generic function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function `api` that takes a parser function. The parser is generic and for example returns the same type that was given to it as input (it's not always like that, just for simplification).

In the `api` function I know what type will be passed to the parser input (`string` for simplicity is actually determined through templating other parameters passed to the `api` function).

How can I set the return type of an `api` function based on the return type of a `parse` with specifying an argument for its template?

```js
// in the lib
type Parse = <T>(val: T) => any

let api = <P extends Parse>(
  parse: P,
) =>
  parse("xxx") as ???


// somewhere
let identity = <T>(val: T): T => val
let res = api(identity)
```

What I tried:

```js
let api = <P extends Parse>(
  parse: P,
) =>
  parse("xxx") as ReturnType<P<string>> // error "Type P is not generic"
                                        // we can't specify type arguments of generic function type
```

```js
let api = <P extends Parse>(
  parse: P,
) =>
  parse("xxx") as P extends (val: string) => infer O ? O : never // unknown
```

```js
let api = <P extends Parse>(
  parse: P,
) =>
  parse("xxx") as ReturnType<typeof parse<string>> // any, instantiation expression don't work either
```

I want to point out that I do not have access to the implementation of the `parse` function. It can be anything that fits the `Parse` type (which I can change if necessary).

Comment: You can't. TypeScript doesn't have "call types". There's a feature request for this at [ms/TS#40179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179). Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: At the time the `api` function is called, the parser type (template parameter `P`) is known. Is it really impossible to understand based on it what type of data the parser will return? The problem is that this type is generic in itself.

Comment: ```typescript
type Parse = <T>(val: T) => any  

let api = <P extends Parse>(
  parse: P,
) =>
  parse("xxx") as ReturnType<P>

let parse = <T>(val: T): string => ""
let res = api(parse)
```

I mean this will work and the type of `res` will be `string`

Comment: I'm not sure what to say without repeating myself. It's impossible if the output type depends on the input type, which is the point of ms/TS#40179. Of course it will work if the return type doesn't depend on the generic type argument, but that's not what you're asking. Are you just looking for me to reiterate my comment before telling me if it fully addresses your question? Or are you saying I've missed some important aspect of your issue that makes it differ from ms/TS#40719?

Comment: Note that `P extends Parse` does *not* imply that `P` is a generic function type.  Even if you could require that (which would seem to need [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)), there's no way to instantiate its type argument at the type level, see [ms/TS#50481](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50481). But your example doesn't lend itself to the (unsupported) instantiation type `P<T>`, it lends itself to the (unsupported) call type `P(string)`. Do you want to [edit] to show an example where you actually care about generic instantiation and not a call type?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! It's a pity that Typescript doesn't yet allow you to do such things. I just wanted to make sure that this is a current feature of the language and not my ignorance of its capabilities. This seemed possible to me since all types are known at compile time. If you can write up a short answer, that would be great and might help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is beyond TypeScript's abilities.

---

There is no way to ask the question "for a given generic function type `type F = <T>(⋯)=>⋯`, what would the type of the function be if you instantiate the type parameter `T` with the type argument `U`"?  If you had an actual generic function *expression* `f` and not just a *type* `F`, you could use an [instantiation *expression*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) like `f<U>`. But there is no way to perform this operation purely at the type level.  See [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#47607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607#issuecomment-1058192563):

> [I]nstantiation expressions currently have no equivalent in type land. We can't just co-opt the `T<X>` type instantiation syntax since it already means something else (i.e. apply type arguments to the generic type `T`).

Maybe one day there will be such a type-level solution, with some special syntax like `F«U»` or something. But for now it's not possible.

---

But it's even worse than that. You've got a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `P` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Parse`. But that doesn't imply that `P` is a generic function type.  For example, you could call

```
api((x: unknown) => 123); // okay
```

There is no way in TypeScript to talk in the abstract about "generic function types whose call signatures have a single type parameter". That would require something like *higher kinded types* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  So `P` wouldn't be known to accept a type argument, and thus even with hypothetical `F«U»` syntax, `P«string»` wouldn't be allowed.  Or maybe it *would* be allowed but do nothing for nongeneric functions?

And even if so, it gets worse, because you're just assuming that the type parameter is the type of the first function parameter. Otherwise `P«string»` might have nothing to do with the `parse("xxx")` call.  Imagine someone called this:

```
const g = <T,>(x: unknown, y?: T) => y;
// const g: <T>(x: unknown, y?: T | undefined) => T | undefined
api(g)
```

You couldn't expect `g<string>` to have anything to do with the return type of `parse("xxx")`.

---

Indeed, your code example doesn't really look like you want to ask about generics at all.  Instead, you want to ask "given a one-arg function `f` of type `F` and a valid argument `u` of type `U`, what is the type of `f(u)`?  This would require so-called *call types*, which TypeScript also doesn't support, so this is still beyond TypeScript's abilities. There's a feature request for call types at [microsoft/TypeScript#40179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179).  Maybe in the future there will be some syntax like `F(U)` to represent that. And in such a hypothetical world, your example would be

```
// NOT VALID TS, DON'T TRY THIS:
let api = <F extends (x: string) => any>(parse: F): F(string) => 
  parse("xxx");
```

And then when you call `api(identity)` you'd get `string` out as expected, instead of `unknown`.  And it wouldn't *need* the input to be a generic function, just that it can be called like `(x: string) => any`.  Presumably this would also handle [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) like `{(x: string): number; (x: number): string}`.

But again, it's not part of the language.  Right now the closest you can get is [the `ReturnType` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype), which completely fails to resolve generic type arguments or overload call signatures.

---

In conclusion, this isn't possible.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsDtQFwCwKagDbgEYCgYE8AOSAFAQwCcBnJAXlAB4AVAPgAoA3I5ALlDoEpRKGoIpGwYMyBDCG5w-WgVAIAHjASQAJmVDFyCZhlChcpClwIAaDHwEGjJhEwBESl454BuMRhCgyAewBbBAB3RBIEcUkIdTUYcBw5enNmNk5uHi46fkFUyKlwrWoiGSZwGMg4nA8xYvAmJiUuAFdIAGtIP2DIa0EARgAmAGZqjABjP0gyKQBzRLpkhua2jq7zUGwAfkye9c8fccmZrnpmRtAW9s7INc3M0AAfc40EADMoBHUdrMeWmLfID4YWpMaY8Lw+OB4PzwSTgUbsbxgCRSWqJABiihUak0oEWvhgJCgoOyQhEzGMui4aIyoDRTCmhMgxIEdl0ThcSjc7iAA)